# How can I pass two different ID in same tabAdapter?

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, tabs, bundle

In **HomePage**, it has `listView`(retrieve from MySQL) and a `popup Menu` , where the `popup Menu` has a **view** page. **View** also has `listView`.

**HomePage**
[image]

**view**

[image]

When **HomePage** or **View** list is clicked, it will go to **fragment** which has 4 tabs and allow user to do edit  base on the ID.

When **HomePage** list is clicked

```
  public static int ID;
      listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View view,
                                        int position, long id) {
                    ID = search.get(position).getID();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Edit" + ID, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityB.class);
                    intent.putExtra("ID", ID);  // pass to tabAdapter
                    intent.putExtra("name", name); // pass to tabAdapter
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
```

When **View** clicked

```
 public static int ID;
     listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View view,
                                        int position, long id) {
                    ID = search.get(position).getID();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Edit" + ID, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityB.class);
                    intent.putExtra("ID", ID); // pass to tabAdapter
                    intent.putExtra("name", name); // pass to tabAdpter
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
```

**TabAdapter**

```
  public Fragment getItem(int index) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(index == 0) {
            Fragment fragment=new EditInformation();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putInt("ID", HomePage.ID);
            fragment.setArguments(bundle);
            return fragment;

        }
}
```

**EditInformation**

```
 Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            ID = bundle.getInt("ID");
        }
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"SS"+ID,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

When I click the list in HomePage, it display the correct ID in HomePage and EditInformation. But when I click the list in View, it display the correct ID, **but no ID display in EditInformation** .

I add   `bundle.putInt("ID", View.ID);` after   `bundle.putInt("ID", HomePage.ID);`, it works for **All** , but not works for **HomePage** ! The HomePage list display its ID but display 0 id in EditInformation.

How to solve this ???
How can we differentiate whether the list is click from All or View ??? Thanks

Comment: Just to make sure I understand the problem: the ID is transmitted correctly to the same target (ActivityB) by clicking on list item in HomePage but not by clicking on list item in View although you are using the same code in the listener?

Comment: Without something like a minimal, complete etc.... example it's difficult to be sure, but I have a bad feeling about the "**public static** int ID". This way, the ID value has a means of leaking in somehow instead of being transmitted only from its source (View *or* Homepage). If you'd like me to look into this some more then I'd really need enough code to reproduce the error.

Comment: @0X0nosugar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35124362/pass-two-different-id-to-same-tabadapter?noredirect=1#comment57969414_35124362

Comment: Thank you, after reading the comments of the other question I'm even more certain you should not use a public variable for ID. But I also see you have all the help you need :)

Comment: @0X0nosugar thanks for your attention

Comment: @0X0nosugar I still stuck...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102233/discussion-between-john-joe-and-0x0nosugar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put another `Intent` extra to indicate where the user clicked. For example in the `OnItemClickListener` of the `ListView` in **HomePage**:

```
intent.putExtra("FROM_HOME", true);
```

And in the `OnItemClickListener` in the other `ListView`

```
intent.putExtra("FROM_HOME", false);
```

All in all, your `Intent` has three extras which you can get via `getIntent()` in **ActivityB**:

Let's introduce three variables for this activity

```
private int _id;
private String _name;
private boolean _fromHome;
```

Then in `onCreate()` you can get the intent extras like this:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
_id = intent.getIntExtra("ID", -1);
_name = intent.getStringExtra("name");
_fromHome = intent.getBooleanExtra("FROM_HOME", false);
```

Now your activity has all the necessary information to decide what should be done.

Comment: what should I change in tabAdapter ?

Comment: @John Joe  - in the tab adapter you can use the values from ActivityB. You need the ID, so you write "bundle.putInt("ID", _id );" I think you can even better change the constructor for the tab adapter to pass the value of _id ( --> "Encapsulation Is Good"  ;) )